# error en select y autocomple ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hola estoy haciendo un formulario y requiere un *autocomplete* y *selects* pero  en las rutas; cuando voy a guardar me sale un error.

la pantalla  tira un error se queda en  validación.
yo  coloco el  **Log**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código:

**Modelo**

reunion.rb

```
class Reunion < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :centro_costo

  def centro_costo_fullname
    centro_costo.fullname if centro_costo
  end

  def centro_costo_fullname=(fullname)
    self.centro_costo = CentroCosto.find_by_fullname(fullname) unless fullname.blank?
  end
end
```

**Routes**

```
resources :reuniones do
  collection do
    get :autocomplete_centro_costo_fullname
    get :select_region
    get :select_ciudad
    get :select_planta
  end
end
```

**controlador**

```
class ReunionesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_reunion, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

autocomplete  :centro_costo, :fullname, :full => true, :column_name => 'fullname'

```
# GET /reuniones
# GET /reuniones.json
def index
  @reuniones = Reunion.all
  @negocios = Negocio.all
end

def select_region
  rs = Region.where(:negocio_id => params[:idnegocio]).order('nombre').all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json {render json: rs }
    format.html
  end
end

def select_ciudad
  rs = Ciudad.where(:region_id => params[:idregion]).order('nombre').all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json {render json: rs }
    format.html
  end
end

def select_planta
  rs = Planta.where(:ciudad_id => params[:idciudad]).order('nombre').all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json {render json: rs }
    format.html
  end
end

def new
  Time.zone = 'America/Bogota' 
  @reunion = Reunion.new(fecha_entrega: Time.zone.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
  @reunion.detalles_reuniones.build
  @negocios = Negocio.all #para javascript
end

# GET /reuniones/1/edit
def edit
end

# POST /reuniones
# POST /reuniones.json
def create
     centro_costo = CentroCosto.find_by(fullname:reunion_params[:centro_costo_fullname])
    @reunion = Reunion.new(reunion_params)
    @reunion.centro_costo_id = centro_costo.id
  respond_to do |format|
    if @reunion.save!
      format.html { redirect_to @reunion, notice: 'Reunion was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @reunion }
    else
   @negocios = Negocio.all
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @reunion.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

end
centro_costo  es  una asociacion.

```
private
   # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_reunion
     @reunion = Reunion.find(params[:id])
  end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def reunion_params
  params.require(:reunion).permit(:hora_pedido, :fecha_pedido,
  :hora_inicio, :hora_final, :fecha_entrega, :observacion, :subtotal,
  :planta_id, :ubicacion,:centro_costo_fullname,:hora_entre,:nombre,
  #Aca esta el maestro de detalle.
  detalles_reuniones_attributes: [:id,:reunion_id, :cantidad, :valor, :producto_id, :hora_entrega,:_destroy])
end
```

**log**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error se debe a que tu forma está enviando únicamente el atributo `centro_costo_fullname` y tu objeto `Reunion` necesita el atributo `centro_costo_id` (esto por la asociación `belongs_to :centro_costo`).

Entonces al intentar guardar el registro en tu controlador  (i.e. `@reunion.save`), falla la validación ya que no estás dando ese atributo (en rails 5 las relaciones `belongs_to` requieren que el `id` relacionado siempre esté presente a menos que se indique lo contrario).

Para solucionarlo tienes dos opciones.

1. Modificar tu forma para que envíe `centro_costo_id`.
2. Obtener el `id` utilizando `centro_costo_fullname` y asignarlo manualmente.

Yo recomiendo la segunda opción pues considero que es más sencilla. Para ello necesitas obtener el centro de costo a partir de tu modelo y asignar su `id` a `@reunion`.

Por ejemplo, así podrías obtener el centro de costo<sup>1</sup>:

```
centro_costo = CentroCosto.find_by(fullname: reunion_params[:centro_costo_fullname])
```

Y luego asignas el `id` a `@reunion`:

```
@reunion.centro_costo_id = centro_costo.id
```

Entonces, así se vería la acción `create` del controlador:

```
def create
  centro_costo = CentroCosto.find_by(fullname: reunion_params[:centro_costo_fullname])
  @reunion = Reunion.new(reunion_params)
  @reunion.centro_costo_id = centro_costo.id

  respond_to do |format|
    if @reunion.save
      format.html { redirect_to @reunion, notice: 'Reunion was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @reunion }
    else
      @negocios = Negocio.all

      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @reunion.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

<sup>1</sup> *Asumo que tu método `reunion_params` permite el atributo `centro_costo_fullname`.*

---

En caso que la validación siga fallando, puedes modificar tu código para que muestre un error en lugar de regresar un `false` (que en tu log se identifica solo por el `rollback`).

Para hacerlo, en la accion `create` del controlador, cambia esta línea:

```
if @reunion.save
```

Por esta otra:

```
if @reunion.save!
```

Y fíjate en el error que se mostrará en la consola cuando intentes crear una `Reunion`.

Una vez que identifiques el error debes **regresar el código de tu acción `create` a `@reunion.save`**, de lo contrario los usuarios podrán obtener pantallas de error cuando ingresen datos equivocados (en lugar de mensajes más amigables).

Comment: la segunda no me dio como hago  la primera @Gerry, gracias

Comment: @juangomez ¿Te muestra algún error?, ¿qué dicen los logs? Para la primera tendría que ver el código de la vista, ¿puedes compartirla?

Comment: Ya esta  listo el log @gerry

Comment: @juangomez Parece que el log no cambia, así que haz lo siguiente: En tu accion `create` cambia `@reunion.save` por `@reunion.save!` e inténtalo de nuevo. En esta ocasion el log te mostrará un error; sustituye el log que acabas de poner por el que obtengas ahora.

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvio.  gracias @Gerry

Comment: @juangomez Excelente!

Comment: yo organice una variables  y una asociaciones  que tenia mal cada dia  mejoro gracias al conocimiento  que enseñas gracias  y mas  comunidad aumenta muchas gracias.@gerry

Comment: si  el autocomple se queda en blanco  me tira el error anterior @Gerry 
  @ reunion.centro_costo_id = centro_costo.id

Comment: ya esta actualizado si no se llena los selects y autocomple sale un error @Gerry, GRACIAS

Comment: @juangomez Es un comportamiento esperado, ya que el autocomplete tiene el atributo `centro_costo_fullname`, por lo tanto es un campo obligatorio (de acuerdo a tu configuración).

Comment: @juangomez Lo mismo pasa con los selects, al no tener información no se puede guardar el objeto. Lo que debes hacer es agregar validaciones al modelo y que se muestren mensajes de error al usuario, por ejemplo: "debes elegir un negocio".

Comment: hola como estas  me puedes  dar un ejemplo de los selects y autocomplete seria de gran ayuda.muchas gracias.@Gerry

Comment: hola  como cambia esto en un maestro de detalle? @Gerry

Comment: @juangomez No entiendo bien tu pregunta, ¿podrías detallar un poco más?

Comment: la solucion puede cambiar un maestro de detalle es que antes me daba ya no  he buscado y  creo que fue ese cambio. @Gerry  gracias